# How to return a "lighter" version of the data from a Controller?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm using Spring 4.3, and I have a REST Controller that returns a `User` object to the UI (javascript).

The problem is that I get a `User` object from the Database (say with Hibernate) that contains a password. I don't want to expose the password by actually returning it. Instead, I want the controller method to put `NULL` in it before returning it (I could use `Optional` or other solutions to avoid nulls, but I'm keeping it simple in this question).

```
public class User {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    //setters and getters
}

@Controller
public class MainController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/getOne", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User getOneUser() {
        User user = //getUser
        //something to nullify the password?
        return user;
    }
```

This question concerns a User and a password for clarity, but I'm looking for a wide solution that would take care of all my data models and the values I don't want them to include in some returns.

## Solutions I don't like :)

#### Disliked solution #1: Remove the password in a private method or a utility class' method or an Adapter class

I don't like this because it makes the code very long. Most controller methods will need their own adaptation of the data.

I prefer something more clean and short.

#### Disliked solution #2: Use `@JsonIgnore` annotation

I don't want to bind my data models with `Jackson` package.

#### Disliked solution #3: Use a smaller data model class, and blind-copy everything that the smaller can contain

This solution refers to a code such as this:

```
public class ReturnUser {
   private String username;
}

@Controller
public class MainController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/getOne", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User getOneUser() {
        User user = //getUser

        ReturnUser smaller = copyWhatsInCommon(user, User.class, ReturnUser.class); //sees that there's only username common to both, so copies only it
        return smaller;
```

This also increases the quantity of code, so I don't like it.

***Any ideas?***

Comment: `This also increases the quantity of code, so I don't like it.` You cannot create nothing which will not increase quantity of code. All solutions with mappers, interceptors etc. will create more code.

Comment: I meant I'm looking for the best possible way to avoid code duplication, in the sense that a great amount of code does something similar (but not enough identical, to merge) to other pieces of code (adapters for various data models, smaller data models, etc).

Comment: I don't like exposing your Entities into public world. For me you should map entity-dto and hide values in mapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From experience:

1.) You should not return your business objects from the View layer ie Controller. You see this in many tutorials, but this is poor design.

2.) You should create a response object. This response object will only contain the fields you want to return to the user.

3.) You should instantiate the fields for UserResponse in the constructor with the user object.

Using since you are creating a resposne object, you using the @JsonIgnore annotation doesn't make sense.

While this may be more code, it is a better design with a clear separation of responsibility. The controller only needs to worry about the view object and the business layer never needs to know anything about the view.

Ex

```
public class UserResponse {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public UserResponse(User user){
        this.firstName = user.getFirstName();
        this.lastName = user.getLastName();
    }

    ...
    //The getters
}
```

In the controller:

```
return new UserResponse(user);
```

Comment: While I tend to agree on the separation of responsibility manner, I'm not convinced that it's worth the complication. You wrote `You should not return your business objects from the View layer ie Controller. You see this in many tutorials, but this is poor design.` Could you please elaborate and explain why it's poor designing? If I drop information from the service's data model, and preferably don't even let the controller's client know of the information I drop (there won't even be a "password" field in the response JSON), then what do I lose?

Comment: It's poor design because you are preparing the view in the business logic. Assuming you are calling someService.getUser - You are passing business object directly to the view. The view layer(controller) should handle what is returned in the view.

Comment: Creating response objects does add another layer of complexity, but it simplifies things in the long run, because you will always be able to return the same user object to the view layer, but have different views based on the controller method.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**:
You can add a transformation layer between your controller and the facade (or the service which populates the entity from the database). The transformation layer classes can convert the `entities` into `value objects`. The VOs will only contain the minimal information that your `view` needs. If there are more entities than 1 that you need to transform into value objects, you can also use `reflections` to read the properties (from a config file or something) that need to be read from the entities and copied to the VOs. However, this is not quite different from the solution 3 in your question that you don't like much. While it serves from performance and security perspective, it does add additional code in form of a transformation layer.

**Option 2**: An alternate and straightforward option I can propose is read the required attributes from 'User' class and populate them as `model attributes`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/getOne", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User getOneUser(ModelMap modelMap) {
    User user = //getUser
    modelMap.addAttribute("userName", user.getName());
    modelMap.addAttribute("userEmail", user.getEmail());
    ...
    ...
}
```

}

Comment: Do I define each VO on the basis of the original data model? Meaning, would a VO look like `ReturnUser` in my disliked solution #3? 

I'm looking for a way to avoid the duplication...

Using `ModelMap` seems even more complicated, since I can't use reflection (in my example: `copyWhatsInCommon`)

Comment: Yes, `VO` looksl like 'ReturnUser' class. with `ModelMap` approach, there is no need to use `reflection` unless you can explain me the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want absolutely to return the User as it is represented in your entity?

The service and the controller layers should even not get a User object that contains a password field. So your 1 and 3 solution should be avoided.

In your case returning a view of the `User` class seems the most relevant way to achieve your need. Just use a DTO

Either you could return the User DTO from a service layer that accesses to the Data Access layer.

Or if you don't have a service layer, you could provide a method in the data access layer that returns a User DTO without the password field.

Comment: Ok. But if it is not adapted it would make no sense for you. How do you retrieve the user from the Controller ? Please detail the calls.

Comment: I'm using a simple AJAX call. I don't want to set my server side according to the client side, so I don't want to add a sample code... Let's just focus how the Controller method deals with the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to offer one more solution. Just for coverage. This is very ugly and not recommended. You can create an object mapper and filter the object:

```
static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

public static String filterOutAllExcept(Object obj, String filterName, String... properties) throws YpException {

    mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate4Module());
    SimpleBeanPropertyFilter filter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept(properties);
    FilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter(filterName, filter).setFailOnUnknownId(false);
    String strValue;
    try {
        strValue = mapper.writer(filterProvider).writeValueAsString(obj);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        // handle exception

    }

    return strValue;
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
String filterApplied = ObjectMapperHelper.filterOutAllExcept(user, JsonDTOFilter.SOMEFILTER, "firstName", "lastName");
```

This will give you a json string with the fields firstName and lastName